# When I set a break point in GDB, for c++ file, where exactly does it break?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I want to know where exactly would it break, and what it would execute prior and posterior to this event
2 cases: line and function

Line case:

```
(gdb) break test.c:851
```

code:

```
850 setup();
851 return configure();
852
```

Would this execute configure()? or not

Function case:

```
(gdb) TestClass::initialize()
```

code:

```
849 initialize(){
850 setup();
851 return configure();
852
```

Would it execute setup()?

Comment: The debugger stops the program just before the very first machine instruction of the code named in the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the breakpoint stops **before** the first instruction of the source line you are on when compiled for debug.  When the code is optimized, however, inlining and instruction rearrangement can cause [unintuitive results](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2008-10/msg00200.html). To be sure, set your breakpoint on an assembly instruction.

Typically it will not execute either your line or the first line of your function.  But you should be aware that there are circumstances where that might not be the case.  Note that gdb depends on information provided to it so results can vary by language/compiler.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, gdb breaks once the code on the previous line has completed. You can verify this by stepping from the breakpoint, you will observe that the code in the configure function will be executed and the value will be returned to line 851 at which point the `return` keyword will kick in and return that value.

Comment: The line case, not sure exactly about the function case